# How to Make JavaScript running inside of Imba's elements?

Tags: javascript, html, imba

I want to run JavaScript that is placed inside Imba's element just like my example below.

**index.imba**

```
tag script-app
    <self>
        <h4> "Running js/ts inside Imba elements"
        <div id='print'>
        <script type="application/javascript">
            document.getElementById('print').innerHTML="Hello"

imba.mount <script-app>
```

That is equivalent to...
**index.html**

```
    <div id="print"></div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = "Hello"
    </script>
```

How to make it to be worked? Should I not to implement <script> like this?

I want to try to implement javascript inside of imba's element same as what I usually do when I am using javascript inside html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close, you want to have the js code inside strings. Check out this interactive video (scrim) to learn more https://scrimba.com/scrim/cWNPppHJ

```
tag script-app
<self>
    <h4> "Running js/ts inside Imba elements"
    <div id='print'>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        'document.getElementById('print').innerHTML="Hello"'
imba.mount <script-app>
```

Comment: just like what I expected, thanks